# Python Numpy array holding another array

Tags: python, numpy

I need to create an array holding another arrays as elements of it, in a way that I could call each of arrays and manipulate the data of it. When I try to append the 'array' to 'array_of_arrays' nothing happens. Maybe there is more Python way how to do this? I have also read that arrays can have multiple ranks. Maybe that is what I need?

`array = np.zeros (mask.shape , uint8)
array_of_arrays = np.array()
np.append(arrays_of_arrays , array)`

Comment: Is there a reason a list of arrays wouldn't work?

Comment: A quick google search returns a lot of answers to your question. What you want basically is an N-Dimensional array. (Or 2-Dimensional in your specific case).
Read the Numpy documentation and update your question if the things there didn't work out for you.

Comment: @jedwards I would assume that a numpy N-dim array would be better than a list of arrays because generally working with pure Numpy data structures would be faster than working with python data structures.

Comment: It would be faster only in the case that you could apply the manipulations to the whole ndarray at once, rather than row-wise/column-wise, etc.  Additionally, if the arrays are of different lengths, a python container of arrays (e.g. list) is often better than a jagged ndarray.

Comment: `np.append` is a function, not a method.  It returns a new array; it does not change `arrays_of_arrays` inplace.  I discourage the use of `np.append`.  Learn how to use `np.concatenate` with all of its gory details.